# How can I make a sequence $u_n$ so that $u_{2n+1}$ is increasing and $u_{2n}$ is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that, the sequence $(u_n)$ so that $u_1 = 1$, $u_{n+1} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{u_n}, \forall n \geqslant 1$ has properties $u_{2n+1}$ is increasing and $u_{2n}$ is decreasing. Now I want to construct more sequences like that. I don't know how to start. How can I construct?

Comment: Lace together an increasing and a decreasing sequence of your choice.

Comment: Also, are you sure about your original claim?

Comment: What are your restrictions? Do you want a one-liner sequence, or can you use piecewise functions to create your sequence?

If the latter is available, then the task is easy. Consider $$a_n = \begin{cases}n, & n \text{ odd}\\ {1\over n^2}, & n \text{ even.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I want a one-liner sequence.

Comment: @Decaf-Math Can you give me not a piecewise functions?

Comment: Also as @Randall suggests, you could say that $u_{2n} = a_n$ where $a_n$ is decreasing and $u_{2n+1} = b_n$ where $b_n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be any increasing sequence and $b_n$ any decreasing sequence. Then
$$u_n=(1+(-1)^n)a_n+(1-(-1)^n)b_n$$
has the property you want.

Answer (score 3):

One example is
$$u_n = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$$